# how to get an jquery ui (autocomplete) and fancybox to play nicely

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, fancybox, z-index

I'm having a problem with autocomplete inside a `fancybox`.

The problem arises from `fancybox` overlaying the `div` box that contains the results. Autocomplete works fine but the results are returned behind (not visible) the `fancybox`

How can I fix this?

```
$('#calendar-wrapper').on('click','#calendar td[data-day]',function(){
            $.fancybox({href: '#newapp', title : 'New appointment'  });
            $("#newapp input[name='app_time']").val($(this).closest('tr').attr('data-hr')+':00:00');
            $("#newapp input[name='app_date']").val($(this).attr('data-day'));
        });////END OF FANCYBOX TRIGGER
     var cache = {};
    $(".ac").on('keyup.autocomplete', function(){
        var fun = $(this).attr("data-ac");
        var par=$(this).closest('FIELDSET');
        var el=$(this);
        par.find('input').not(this).val('');
        par.find('select option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var term = request.term,baseurl='<?=base_url()?>';
                if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
                }
                var url=baseurl+'ajax/ac/'+fun+'/'+encodeURIComponent(term);
                $.getJSON( url, '', function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                response( data );
                }).complete(function() {$('.ui-autocomplete-loading').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading'););
            },
            select: function(event, ui){
                for (var key in ui.item) 
                {
                var obj = ui.item[key];
                var f=par.find('[name*="'+key+'"]').first();
                if(f.length){
                    if(f.tagName == 'select'){
                        f.find('option[value="'+obj+'"]').first().attr('selected','selected');
                    }else{
                        f.val(obj);
                    }
                }
                }
            },
            messages: {noResults: '',results: function() {}}
        }); 
    });////END OF AUTOCOMPLETE
```

How can I alter the z-index of the `div` containing the `jquery-ui-ac` results to show them above the `fancybox`?

Comment: have you tried to overwrite the z-index of autocomplete? .ui-front {
    z-index: 10000;
}

Comment: yp the jquery overwrite it

Comment: try `.css()` like `$(this).autocomplete(...).css('z-index', 10000)`

Comment: didnt  work either :(

Answer (score 3):

I used this, and it works for me.

```
<style>
     .ui-autocomplete.ui-front.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all {
         z-index: 10000 !important;
     }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

i faced the same issue

try

```
open: function(){
           $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 999999);
           return false;
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

This was enough to fix the issue (tested with fancybox 2.1.5, jquery-ui 1.11.4):

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
'create': function(){$(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index",100000);}
```

to the autocomplete

```
$("#pagelink").autocomplete({
        'source':'includes/loadvals-sql-ajax.php?table=Categories',
        'minLength': 3,
        'create': function(){$(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index",100000);}
        });
```